# Sequence Exception thrown in Xamarin.Forms custom control

Tags: android, exception, xamarin.forms, custom-controls

I have a very basic cross platform application. The solution contains a PCL for the app injection, and an Android app.

My MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Crossplatform.app"
             xmlns:dragonfly="clr-namespace:Crossplatform.control;assembly=Crossplatform.control"
             x:Class="Crossplatform.app.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <dragonfly:Wizard DataItem="{Binding WizardData}" />

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private string wizarddata;
    public string WizardData
    {
        get { return wizarddata; }
        set { wizarddata = value; }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WizardData = "Hello from ViewModel";
    }
}
```

All this is doing, is defining a string property which I then assign to a BindableProperty in a custom control.

Custom control code:

```
public class Wizard : StackLayout
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty DataContextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: nameof(DataItem),
            returnType: typeof(string),
            declaringType: typeof(Wizard),
            defaultValue: "Show Me",
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            validateValue: null,
            propertyChanged: OnDataContextPropertyChanged);

    public string DataItem
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(DataContextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(DataContextProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public Wizard()
    {

    }

    static void OnDataContextPropertyChanged(BindableObject obj, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```

Nothing crazy here. All I'm doing is defining a bindable property called DataContextProperty, and using this property to notify changes on DataItem property, exposed through the control (per main.xaml above).

The code successfully hits the ctor for the Wizard control, but falls through and fails in Android's MainActivity with a Sequence exception, the stack trace below.

I have been debugging this for the last 4 hours and cannot see why it's failing on the given stack.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm sure what I have here, is perfectly valid.

Stack Trace:

```
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Func`2[T,TResult] predicate) [0x00011] in <b5bd9d990a0b4733885e90ca5ec6c0fb>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.TryAddToProperty (System.Object element, System.String localName, System.Object value, System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineInfo, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Internals.XamlServiceProvider serviceProvider, System.Exception& exception) [0x0005d] in C:\agent\_work\3\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:510 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.SetPropertyValue (System.Object xamlelement, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XmlName propertyName, System.Object value, System.Object rootElement, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydratationContext context, System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo lineInfo) [0x000a2] in C:\agent\_work\3\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:334 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode node, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00152] in C:\agent\_work\3\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ApplyPropertiesVisitor.cs:124 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x000ab] in C:\agent\_work\3\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:149 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00043] in C:\agent\_work\3\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:143 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode.Accept (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.IXamlNodeVisitor visitor, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.INode parentNode) [0x00043] in C:\agent\_work\3\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlNode.cs:201 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Visit (Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.RootNode rootnode, Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.HydratationContext visitorContext) [0x0007b] in C:\agent\_work\3\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:141 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.String xaml) [0x0004b] in C:\agent\_work\3\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:89 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (System.Object view, System.Type callingType) [0x0002f] in C:\agent\_work\3\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\XamlLoader.cs:68 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[TXaml] (TXaml view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in C:\agent\_work\3\s\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml\ViewExtensions.cs:36 
  at Crossplatform.app.MainPage.InitializeComponent () [0x00001] in C:\repos\Crossplatform.app\Crossplatform.app\Crossplatform.app\obj\Debug\Crossplatform.app.MainPage.xaml.g.cs:19 
  at Crossplatform.app.MainPage..ctor () [0x00008] in C:\repos\Crossplatform.app\Crossplatform.app\Crossplatform.app\MainPage.xaml.cs:21 
  at Crossplatform.app.App..ctor () [0x0000f] in C:\repos\Crossplatform.app\Crossplatform.app\Crossplatform.app\App.xaml.cs:16 
  at Crossplatform.app.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00028] in C:\repos\Crossplatform.app\Crossplatform.app\Crossplatform.app.Android\MainActivity.cs:25
```

Comment: You can start adding this line to the MainPage ctor,  `this.BindingContext = this; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code successfully hits the ctor for the Wizard control, but falls through and fails in Android's MainActivity with a Sequence exception, the stack trace below.
>
> I have been debugging this for the last 4 hours and cannot see why it's failing on the given stack.

You are getting this exception because you defined a public property(DataItem) with different Xaml Property Name(`DataContextProperty`), which is not allowed.

To fix the problem, you need to change `DataContextProperty` to `DataItemProperty`.